# Using JQuery Validate to see if atleast one set of radiobuttons is checked yes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Have a simple form. That I need to validate that atleast one of the contacts Has Local radio button checked Yes.  How do I do that with JQ Validate??

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/davetoolin/dGsQR/1/

Here is the html

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="#">
<fieldset>Contact 1
    <input class="name" id="name1" type="text" name="name1" size="20" maxlength=30>
    <br>Local:
    <input class="local" id="local1" type="radio" name="local1" Value="Y">Yes
    <input class="local" id="local1" type="radio" name="local1" Value="N">No
    <p>Contact 2
        <input class="name" id="name2" type="text" name="name2" size="20" maxlength=30>
        <br>Local
        <input class="local" id="local2" type="radio" name="local2 " Value="Y ">Yes
        <input class="local" id="local2" type="radio" name="local2 " Value="N ">No
        <p>Contact 3
            <input class="name" id="name3" type="text" name="name3" size="20" maxlength=30>
            <br>Local
            <input class="local" id="local3" type="radio" name="local3 " Value="Y ">Yes
            <input class="local" id="local3" type="radio" name="local3 " Value="N ">No
            <P>
                <input type="submit" />
</fieldset>
```

And the JS

```
   $('#submit').click(function() {
$('#mailer').submit();
return false;
 });
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $("#contact").validate({
     rules: {
         name1: {
             required: true
         },
         local1: {
             required: function(element) {
          return $('.local:checked').val() == "Y";
        }
         messages: {
             name1: {
                 required: "Name Required"
             },
         local1: {
            required: "At least one contact must be local"
        }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little trick, i dont know if it's optimal but it work.

I made an input `type='text'` invisible for the eye but not `display: none;`

I added a name and created a custom validation :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkLocal', function(value, element){
    var formValid = false
    $('.local:checked').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Y")formValid = true;
    })
    return formValid;
}, 'Please check something')
```

Added in the HTML the input where i wanted the error to show up and create a rule on this input :

```
'checkError':{'checkLocal' : true}
```

Then, the validation work!

Joining a fiddle as proof : http://jsfiddle.net/dGsQR/3/

Comment: Still digesting this but your fiddle is perfect.  Guess to check all the buttons you need the each function, hence the need for the new method.
Having that error show up separately is probably the right behavior anyways.  Your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works great, guess I need to learn a bit more about addMethod.

Answer (score 1):

Well, only one element on a page can have the same ID. You could try something like this

```
if (($("input[name='local1']:checked").length > 0) | ($("input[name='local2']:checked").length > 0) | ($("input[name='local1']:checked").length > 0)){
  // one ore more checkboxes are checked
}
else{
 // no checkboxes are checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for :

```
if($('.local:checked').val() == "Y"){
    //Form is valid
}
```

Comment: Can I build that in to a custom rule??

Comment: Sorry, the JQ validate plugin has rules and messages.  Trying it now,

Comment: Think I got something, make an other anwser!